# How to configure the .hosts file so another device can access it

Tags: flask, hosts

I saw the post https://superuser.com/questions/1523680/how-to-set-up-local-domain-name-home but I am a windows user.

So let's say I setup my domain example.com setting it to my private Ip address.

Then my website sends to website on port 80

I can open it fine on my pc.

But I can't open it on a other local pc on my network.
My website works just fine.
It works on my pc, just not an other on my network.

How would I do this?

Comment: You could set up the hosts on your local router, as long as the local router is used for DNS resolution. That way you can make your local network know about the name => ip resolution, without having to register an actual domain and making a DNS entry.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have router access :/

Comment: Run a DNS forwarding server on one of your computers then change the DNS-server entry on the other computers to the ip of that computer.

Comment: What if I don't have access to those computers

Comment: Then you'll have to register an actual domain (through a domain registrar) and set up the local ip information in the DNS entry for that domain. i.e. set up `app.foo.com` to point to `192.168.x.x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MatsLindh pointed out in the comments, what I am trying to do is impossible without router access. They also stated that I could register a domain. Thanks for telling me!